# recognize phone number using "()" for area code

Tags: regex, phone-number

I need to recognize a phone number on a long string,
now I am using this regex

```
(((\d)(-)?)+){7,15}|\*\d{3,10}|\d{3,10}\*
```

but that does not recognize any one of these formats:

```
(734) 555 1212
(734) 555.1212
(734) 555-1212
(734) 5551212
(734)5551212
```

with "()",

How can I change it to support also these formats?

Comment: I've [answered](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30140087/3764814) a very similar question yesterday. In the answer, I tried to explain the general methodology to get the expression you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this updated regex:

```
\(\d{3}\)\s*\d{3}[\s.-]?\d{4}\b|\*\d{3,10}|\d{3,10}\*
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/cG1fR4/3)

Explanation of the updated part:

- `\(` - literal round brackets
- `\d{3}` - match 3 digits
- `\)` - closing round bracket
- `\s*` - optional whitespace
- `\d{3}` - 3 digits
- `[\s.-]?` - 0 or 1 whitespace or dot or hyphen
- `\d{4}` - 4 digits.

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression is very lenient - it will recognize `1-2-3-4-5-6-7-` as a valid phone number, which would of course be a false positive. If you would like to keep the same level of leniency, replace the optional dash `-` in your expression with an optional character group that includes parentheses, spaces, and a dash:

```
[(]?(((\d)([() .-]+)?)+){7,18}|\*\d{3,10}|\d{3,10}\*
```

[Demo.](https://regex101.com/r/tH2bB2/1)

Of course this expression will bring even more false positives, because it accepts anything that looks remotely close to a phone number.

Comment: @ShaharZer You are welcome. If the problem is solved, consider accepting the answer to let others know that you are no longer looking for additional help with the question.